# What is the best way to show labels in API using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to develop API for game labels, like `High Score`, `Top Users`, `24 Accidents` etc. Since we have multiple games so labels won't be same for each game.

There is localization feature available in laravel which is responsible for multi language as far as I know.

So is this good practise to store labels through laravel localization or should I store into database for each game?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you develop an endpoint to return content of translation file base on locale input.

Answer (score 0):

both,
you can save locales in database in load in localization feature files
I have tried this method before and it was fully responsive to my task